# How to use export excel file with excel 1.1.5 package

Tags: excel, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm currently using this package [Excel 1.1.5](https://pub.dev/packages/excel#lets-get-started) ... It currently has a method called save but it just returns a List integers...and I don't know where to go from here..

```
    List<int>? potato = excel.save(fileName: 'namePotato');
```

**Hoping you guys can help!
Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, you can use [dart:io](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) and I've also used [Permissions_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

```
    Future exportReport() async {
    var excel = Excel.createExcel();
    DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
    String _name = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_now);
    String _fileName = 'surname-' + _name;

    List<int>? potato = excel.save(fileName: _name);

    PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/$_fileName.xlsx').writeAsBytes(potato!, flush: true).then((value) {
        log('saved');
      });
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      log('Denied. Show a dialog with a reason and again ask for the permission.');
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      log('Take the user to the settings page.');
    }

    return null;
  }
```